# Is CSS parallax scrolling possible with existing this HTML structure? (different speeds not background fixed)

Tags: css, parallax

The CSS 'keithclark' solution for parallax scrolling uses the following HTML structure:
(i.e. where the background & foreground are in separate elements)

```
<body>
  <div class="parallax">
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back">
      <div class="title">This is the background</div>
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
      <div class="title">This is the foreground</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The HTML structure I have (which I can't easily change) has:
(an outer fullwidth 'background' entity - which contains an inner max-width:1200px entity containing the foreground contents)

```
<body>
   <div class="outerWrapper" style="background-image: url(example.jpg);">
      <div class="innerWrapper">
         <div>This is the foreground contents</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

I can easily FIX the background  by using 'background-attachment: fixed;' in the outerWrapper.
But I haven't found a way of scrolling the background & foreground at different speeds.
IS there a CSS only solution?